# how is ddr4 controlled on the laptop

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ram, ddr

I am a student of electrical engineering and my previous term's project was implementing ddr2 SDRAM with Xilinx FPGA, but I am interested to know which device on the laptop control ddr4 on it?

and what is the method of controlling that in the computer?

Comment: what do you mean by "control"?

Comment: @PlasmaHH
as you know; the ram has to be controlled by a controller(often processor) to receive and transmit data; my intention is this.

Comment: @hojjat an intention is about *doing something*. What do you want to *do*? Your question is a bit unclear... As the others have explained, there's a memory controller in every computer, and that acts as gateway between a CPU core bus and the DDR4 bus. Which bus that is depends on the individual CPU architecture; wikipedia has plenty of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDR4 is **RAM memory** which in almost any PC is connected to the **memory controller**. That memory controller sits either in the "North bridge" chip (older designs) or in the CPU itself (almost any laptop supporting DDR4).

Even when the RAM connects directly to the CPU (chip) it does not connect to the CPU (core) directly. There will be a memory controller in between. That memory controller will simply be a circuit included on the same silicon die also used for the CPU (core).

The type (specification) of the memory is not directly related to where the RAM connects to. The memory controller determines which type of memory is supported. Changing from DDR2 to DDR4 doesn't mean the memory needs to be connected differently, it means the controller needs to support the memory type that is used.

Also read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller)

Comment: do you mean the controller of the ddr4 is CPU(in the modern laptops) or some other chip control that?

Comment: No, read carefully: the memory controller is inside the chip that also contains the CPU. The CPU cannot connect to the memory directly. A memory controller is always needed. That circuit just sits right next to the CPU itself on the same chip. The CPU is **not** the memory controller.

Comment: oh, ok.
thanks.
I have another problem; that controller is ASIC or programmable? I mean, the method of transmitting and receiving data can be changed?

Comment: @hojjat you can't change it. it's configurable (within boundaries), but it's silicon designed for a specific industry standard (JEDEC something something DDR4), and energy efficiency, waste heat and speed are so important, that it would make no commercial or general sense whatsoever to implement it as anything but hardwired electronics. Note that interfacing DDR4 is only partially a digital problem: A significant amount of the problem lies in interpreting the analog signals as digital signals (recovering the bits). That's why you effectively need, even in an FPGA, …

Comment: …, even in an FPGA, a dedicated DDR4 interface if you want to talk to DDR4 memory at significant clock speeds. The fact that you can talk to DDR2 memory with your FPGA is because your FPGA already has differential line drivers, SERDESes, and other silicon facilities built in that are "awesome" enough to speak DDR2.

Comment: @Marcus Müller
bless you, Marcus.
I understand that